# Select rows in postgres table where an array field contains NULL

Tags: postgresql

Our system uses postgres for its database.

We have queries that can select rows from a database table where an array field in the table contains a specific value, e.g.:

Find which employee manages the employee with ID 123.

`staff_managed_ids` is a postgres array field containing an array of the employees that THIS employee manages.

This query works as expected:

```
select *
from employees
where 123=any(staff_managed_ids)
```

We now need to query where an array field contains a postgres NULL.  We tried the following query, but it doesn't work:

```
select *
from employees
where NULL=any(staff_managed_ids)
```

We *know* the `staff_managed_ids` array field contains NULLs from other queries.

Are we using NULL wrongly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NULL can not be compared using `=`. The only operators that work with that are `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL`.

To check for nulls, you need to unnest the elements:

```
select e.*
from employees e
where exists (select *
              from unnest(e.staff_managed_ids) as x(staff_id)
              where x.staff_id is null);
```

Answer (score 0):

if all your id values are positive, you could write something like this:

```
select *
from employees
where (-1 < all(staff_managed_ids)) is null;
```

how this works is that -1 should be less than all values, however comparison with null will make the whole array comparison expression null.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - although it's more compact, we couldn't guarantee that every existing id would be > -1, so the answer from @a_horse_with_no_name is more apt in our case.